# How to calculate cumulative proportion of Likert-type responses in r?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to provide a basic summary of my Likert-type (5-point) survey results.
I know how we can use basic mathematical functions across subgroups using the aggregate function. For instance, I can produce means of each item across subgroups but I do not know how to get a percentage of occurrence of more than 2 possible responses across all items.

I have always used SPSS to aggregate the proportion of positive responses (say 4 and 5) for each item across subgroups. So, as a result, I received percentages of positive responses (favorability) for each item broken down by subgroups.

```r
### What I can produce
aggregate(dataset[items], by=subgroup, FUN=mean)
### What I am trying to produce
aggregate(datase[items], by=subgroup, FUN=[proportion of 4 and 5 choices on each item])
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a combination of `aggregate` and `ave` (the inline aggregation function which keeps same number of rows as input). Specifically, count the likert values per subgroup with `aggregate` (using formula style for easier read with `cbind` to rename column), then calculate the ratio of each count by entire subgroup count for proportion percentage with `ave`.

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(count=some_num_col) ~ likert + subgroup, dataset, FUN=length)

agg_df$prop <- with(agg_df, count / ave(count, subgroup, FUN=sum))

agg_df
```

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data (to be replaced with OP's data). Below assumes *likert* in long format but can be reshaped from wide:

**Data**

```
set.seed(8302019)
dataset <- data.frame(
  subgroup = sample(c("sas", "stata", "spss", "python", "r", "julia"), 500, replace=TRUE),
  likert = sample(1:5, 500, replace=TRUE),
  some_num_col = 1
)

head(dataset, 20)
#    subgroup likert some_num_col
# 1     julia      5            1
# 2    python      1            1
# 3      spss      5            1
# 4       sas      1            1
# 5       sas      4            1
# 6      spss      2            1
# 7         r      5            1
# 8         r      5            1
# 9         r      1            1
# 10     spss      3            1
# 11     spss      4            1
# 12      sas      3            1
# 13     spss      5            1
# 14     spss      1            1
# 15     spss      2            1
# 16      sas      4            1
# 17        r      2            1
# 18      sas      4            1
# 19      sas      4            1
# 20     spss      1            1
```

**Proportion by Subgroup**

```
agg_df <- aggregate(cbind(count=some_num_col) ~ likert + subgroup, dataset, FUN=length)

agg_df$prop <- with(agg_df, count / ave(count, subgroup, FUN=sum))

agg_df
#    likert subgroup count      prop
# 1       1    julia    21 0.2359551
# 2       2    julia    16 0.1797753
# 3       3    julia    18 0.2022472
# 4       4    julia    17 0.1910112
# 5       5    julia    17 0.1910112
# 6       1   python    14 0.1891892
# 7       2   python    16 0.2162162
# 8       3   python    16 0.2162162
# 9       4   python    16 0.2162162
# 10      5   python    12 0.1621622
# 11      1        r    20 0.2061856
# 12      2        r    19 0.1958763
# 13      3        r    26 0.2680412
# 14      4        r    17 0.1752577
# 15      5        r    15 0.1546392
# 16      1      sas    18 0.1956522
# 17      2      sas    16 0.1739130
# 18      3      sas    24 0.2608696
# 19      4      sas    18 0.1956522
# 20      5      sas    16 0.1739130
# 21      1     spss    13 0.1688312
# 22      2     spss    22 0.2857143
# 23      3     spss    15 0.1948052
# 24      4     spss    16 0.2077922
# 25      5     spss    11 0.1428571
# 26      1    stata    17 0.2394366
# 27      2    stata     8 0.1126761
# 28      3    stata    16 0.2253521
# 29      4    stata    12 0.1690141
# 30      5    stata    18 0.2535211
```

Comment: I just need to add the prop values corresponding to likert 4 and 5 values. What do you think is the best way to go about that?

Comment: Simply subset from final dataset: `agg_df[agg_df$likert %in% c(4,5),]` or filter before aggregation.