# How to aggregate Likert-Type Scales across subgroups in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to aggregate the cumulative proportion of specific response options (in this case choices 4 and 5) for subgroups on a Likert-type scale questionnaire.

This way I would have the average favorability (in this case options 4 and 5 correspond to "agree" and "strongly agree" on the scale) for each subgroup across questions.

I have figured out a way to this for each separate item with following this post [How to calculate cumulative proportion of Likert-type responses in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728697/how-to-calculate-cumulative-proportion-of-likert-type-responses-in-r/57729046?noredirect=1#comment101908767_57729046), but **I want to see if I can simplify it more by just creating a function that automatically does the same thing for all items**. The dataset I am actually using has 99 items and you can see that it could become painful repeating the same code for each of them.

Here in the replicable example, my dataset has 2 questions named "Q1" and "Q2" (each on a 5-point scale) and subgroup codes named "subgroup". The "some_num_col" is just a variable created as an anchor to generate counts for aggregate function. The "A-rollup" variable is created to recode observations that fell under certain rollups.

```
# Creating the dataset and rollups variable
set.seed(8302019)
dataset <- data.frame(
  subgroup = sample(c(1000,1005,807,886,779,458,557,628), 500, replace=TRUE),
  Q1 = sample(1:5, 500, replace=TRUE), Q2 = sample(1:5, 500, replace =TRUE),
  some_num_col = 1
)
str(dataset)

dataset$A_rollup <- with(dataset,ifelse(subgroup %in% c(1005,1000),1,ifelse(subgroup %in% c(807),2,ifelse(subgroup %in% c(886,779,458),3,ifelse(subgroup %in% c(557,628),4,"N/A")))))

# Aggregate Q1
agg_Q1 <- aggregate(cbind(count=some_num_col) ~ Q1 + A_rollup, dataset, FUN=length)

agg_Q1$prop <- with(agg_Q1, count / ave(count, A_rollup, FUN=sum))

filtered <- agg_Q1[agg_Q1$Q1 %in% c(4,5),]

Final_Q1 <- aggregate(filtered$prop, by=list(filtered$A_rollup), FUN=sum, na.rm=T)

names(Final_Q1) <- c("A_rollup", "Q1.Fav")

remove(filtered,agg_Q1)

# Aggregate Q2
agg_Q2 <- aggregate(cbind(count=some_num_col) ~ Q2 + A_rollup, dataset, FUN=length)

agg_Q2$prop <- with(agg_Q2, count / ave(count, A_rollup, FUN=sum))

filtered <- agg_Q2[agg_Q2$Q2 %in% c(4,5),]

Final_Q2 <- aggregate(filtered$prop, by=list(filtered$A_rollup), FUN=sum, na.rm=T)

names(Final_Q2) <- c("A_rollup", "Q2.Fav")

remove(filtered,agg_Q2)

# Binding the aggregates
Final <- cbind(Final_Q1, Final_Q2$Q2.Fav)
```

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please reduce your code to a minimum that reproduces your issue when copy-pasted? Don't forget the data ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `case_when()` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
mutate_at(.vars = c("Q1","Q2",..), .funs = funs(. = case_when(
          . < 5 ~ 0,
          . >= 5 ~ 1
        )))
```

The .vars selection can be done via named vectors as in the example or selection by position (e.g. `.vars = 2:10`)